# Assign Methods to Events with Array C#

Tags: c#, events, methods

I am using WPF C# VS.

I have to create something arround 100 buttons and Every single one should have its own Event.I also don't want to create them my self.

For example:

The 1. Button Collors all the other Buttons red.
The 2. Button Opens a new Window.
The 3. Button Shows a MessageBox.
...
Everyone does something else!!

So the Question is how can i store Methods in Arrays?

It should work something like that:

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();    //Contains all buttons
void fillButtonsList() {...}                  //Storing Buttons in list
Method[] methods = new Method[]               //Storing Methods in Arrays
{
    colorAll,
    openWindow,
    showMessageBox,
    ...
}
void ApplyEvents()                            //Assign Methods to Events
{
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.Length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].Click += methods[i];
    }
}
void colorAll() {...}                         //Methos get Executed when Event got Fired
void openWindow() {...}
void showMessageBox() {...}
...
```

I hope you understand my question my english in't very good.

Comment: use `Action` instead of `Method`?

Comment: or perhaps `EventHandler` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();    //Contains all buttons
void fillButtonsList() {...}                  //Storing Buttons in list
Action[] methods = new Action[]               //Storing Methods in Arrays
{
    colorAll,
    openWindow,
    showMessageBox,
    ...
}
void ApplyEvents()                            
{
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.Length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].Click += (s, e) => methods[i].Invoke();
    }
}
void colorAll() {...}                         
void openWindow() {...}
void showMessageBox() {...}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself:

```
ContextMenu cm1 = new ContextMenu();
(string, bool, ContextMenu, RoutedEventHandler)[] ContextMenuInfo = new (string, bool, ContextMenu, RoutedEventHandler)[]
{
    ("1", false, cm1, event1),
    ("2", false, cm1, event2),
    ("3", false, cm1, event3),
    ("4", false, cm1, event4),
    ("5", false, cm1, event5)
};
foreach ((string, bool, ContextMenu, RoutedEventHandler) item in ContextMenuInfo)
{
    MenuItem mi = MakeContextMenuMenuItem(item.Item1, item.Item2);
    mi.Click += item.Item4;
    item.Item3.Items.Add(mi);
}
void event1() {...}
void event2() {...}
void event3() {...}
void event4() {...}
void event5() {...}

private MenuItem MakeContextMenuMenuItem(string text, bool bold = false)
{
    TextBlock tbb = new TextBlock();
    if (bold)
    {
        tbb.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(text)));
    }
    else
    {
        tbb.Text = text;
    }
    MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
    mi.Header = tbb;
    return mi;
}
```